# Generate and optimize FP / SIMD code in the Linux Kernel on files which contains kernel_fpu_begin()?

Tags: linux-kernel, cryptography, compiler-optimization, simd, fpu

I know that it's forbidden to use any kind of floating-point code in the kernel, and we never should use any GCC flag that could generate FP / SIMD instructions, but what about some source code (especially `arch/x86/crypto/*`) that uses `kernel_fpu_begin()` and `kernel_fpu_end()`?

[Example 1](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/arch/x86/lib/mmx_32.c?h=v4.14.177#n285), [example 2](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/arch/x86/crypto/sha512_ssse3_glue.c?h=v4.14.177#n59).

I have an ancient Intel Core 2 Duo CPU that I use for my 64-bit Linux Kernel and in the main `Makefile` I use the following C flags:

```
# Target specific Flags
KBUILD_CFLAGS   += \
           -m64 \
           -march=core2 \
           -mtune=core2 \
           -mfpmath=sse \
           -msoft-float \
           -mno-fp-ret-in-387 \
           -mno-mmx \
           -mno-sse \
           -mno-sse2 \
           -mno-sse3 \
           -mno-ssse3

# FPU Flags
FPU_CFLAGS := $(KBUILD_CFLAGS) \
           -mhard-float \
           -mfp-ret-in-387 \
           -mmmx \
           -msse \
           -msse2 \
           -msse3 \
           -mssse3 \
           -ftree-vectorize
```

and in files where `kernel_fpu_begin()` is present, I pass the `FPU_CFLAGS` in their `Makefiles` like this:

```
CFLAGS_sha512_ssse3_glue.o := $(FPU_CFLAGS)
```

Is this correct and will it optimize the FP / SIMD code? Or is it not needed and this implementation could even break the state of the FPU / SIMD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this correct

**No, absolutely do not do this.**  These options tell GCC it can use SIMD/FP instructions *anywhere* in this compilation unit, including *before* `kernel_fpu_begin()` or after `kernel_fpu_end()`, or in functions that never call `kernel_fpu_begin()`.

e.g. it could emit a `movdqu` load or store to copy 16 bytes of a struct and [corrupt user-space XMM register state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15883947/why-am-i-able-to-perform-floating-point-operations-inside-a-linux-kernel-module) *before* `kernel_fpu_begin` saved it.

> and will optimize the FP / SIMD Code?

No, kernel code that uses `kernel_fpu_begin()` also uses inline asm to run SIMD instructions.  That will emit SIMD instructions *without* any help from the compiler.

Or in theory some kernel code could use a function attribute like `__attribute__((target("sse2")))` or something like that for a helper function called from inside a `kernel_fpu_begin()` / `end` block.  But I think Linux prefers inline asm instead of that plus intrinsics or auto-vectorization.

**The kernel wouldn't bother to include `kernel_fpu_begin()`/`end` calls if it was getting zero benefit from it**.  BTW, you can disassemble the relevant `.ko` kernel modules and see that they do in fact contain SIMD instructions that use XMM registers.  Use `objdump -drwC -Mintel foo.ko`