# 32-Byte PCIe transaction from Linux driver

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, intel, inline-assembly

I want to do 32 bytes transaction to/from PCIe device inside the Linux driver.
[Compiling Intel AVX instrinsics for Linux Device Driver with GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29240450/13235417)

Code:

```c
base_4 = ioremap(bar_data->bar_paddr[4], bar_data->bar_len[4]);

test_ptr = kmalloc(128, GFP_KERNEL);
if (!test_ptr) {
    printk("test_ptr : kmalloc failed \n");
    return -ENOMEM;
}

memset (test_ptr, 1, 128);

kernel_fpu_begin();   
_mm256_storeu_si256((__m256i*)base_4, *(((__m256i*)test_ptr) + 0));
_mm_mfence();

kernel_fpu_end();
```

Building the file gives error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/include/mm_malloc.h:27:20: fatal error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
 #include <stdlib.h>
           ^
compilation terminated.
```

Makefile:

```makefile
obj-m += memsule.o

ccflags-y := -mavx -mmmx -msse -mpreferred-stack-boundary=4

KDIR = /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build

all:
    make -C $(KDIR) M=$(shell pwd) modules

clean:
    make -C $(KDIR)  M=$(shell pwd) clean
```

Is there any other method How to use the assembly instruction `vmovdqa m256, ymm`?

I tried this way

```asm
 asm volatile("vmovdqa base_4,test_ptr");
```

but got error:

```
 Error: too many memory references for `vmovdqa'
```

How to use the assembly code in C properly?

Comment: Your error looks similar to the one, noted in [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29240450/compiling-intel-avx-instrinsics-for-linux-device-driver-with-gcc#comment46692454_29240920). It seems that [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29240920/3440745) you are following is not correct.

Comment: `stdlib.h` is user space header. You may not use it for kernel modules.

Comment: Using GNU C inline asm is possible, but you of course need to use valid asm instructions, and with GNU C Extended asm syntax to tell the compiler what operands you want.  https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info.  Kernel code is unique in that you maybe should *not* tell the kernel about XMM/YMM registers you clobber, though.

Comment: Oops, meant to link https://stackoverflow.com/tags/inline-assembly/info for info on how to access local vars in GNU C inline asm.  You'll want to `vmovdqu` load into a register and then store.

Comment: how to use this instruction?

Comment: Is it worth saving and restoring state to move 32-bytes?

Comment: @stark don't forget we are talking about IO over PCI bus which is extremely slow.