# Current x86 privilege level on a custom OS

Tags: assembly, x86, privilege

In a custom OS running on an x86 in protected mode, is there a way to obtain the current privilege level, other than e.g. executing a privileged instruction and seeing if it crashes?

For instance, register `CR0` contains the `PE` bit, which indicates if we are running on real mode or protected mode, and can be easily retrieved using assembly code.

Is there something equivalent for the privilege level?

The [Intel architecture software developer manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) mentions that the `EFLAGS` register contains two `IOPL` bits related to I/O privilege levels. Is this the same as the current privilege level (CPL)?

Comment: Do you mean something like `mov ax, cs / and al, 03h`?

Comment: He didn't mention that what he's really trying to do is enable SSE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31563078/how-do-i-enable-sse-for-my-freestanding-bootable-code/, but modifying `CR0` and `CR4` wasn't working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No it's not the same. Those represent the io privilege level. Some instructions such as `IN`, `OUT`, `CLI` require io privileges which are determined using the `IOPL` and the `CPL`.

See also:

> IOPL I/O privilege level field (bits 12 and 13) -- Indicates the I/O
>   privilege
>        level (IOPL) of the currently running program or task. The CPL of the
>        currently running program or task must be less than or equal to the IOPL to
>        access the I/O address space.

The `CPL` can be read simply from the `CS` selector as the two lowest bits:

```
mov ax, cs
and ax, 3
```

This of course only works in protected mode.

Comment: Indeed, very simple once you know it, but not obvious at all when searching for it in the 3603-page long manual.