# What is "MAX" referring to in the intel intrinsics documentation?

Tags: c++, c, intrinsics, avx, avx512

Within the [intel intrinsics guide](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#text=_mm256_mask_permutexvar_ps) some operations are defined using a term "MAX". An example is `__m256 _mm256_mask_permutexvar_ps (__m256 src, __mmask8 k, __m256i idx, __m256 a)`, which is defined as

```
FOR j := 0 to 7
    i := j*32
    id := idx[i+2:i]*32
    IF k[j]
        dst[i+31:i] := a[id+31:id]
    ELSE
        dst[i+31:i] := 0
    FI
ENDFOR
dst[MAX:256] := 0
```

. Please take note of the last line within this definition: `dst[MAX:256] := 0`. What is `MAX` referring to and is this line even adding any valuable information? If I had to make assumptions, then `MAX` probably means the amount of bits within the vector, which is `256` in case of `_mm256`. This however does not seem to change anything for the definition of the operation and might as well have been omitted. But why is it there then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This pseudo-code only makes sense for *assembly* documentation, where it was copied from, not for intrinsics**. ([HTML scrape](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpermps#vpermps--evex-forms-) of Intel's vol.2 PDF documenting the corresponding `vpermps` asm instruction.)

```
   ...
ENDFOR
DEST[MAXVL-1:VL] ← 0
```

(The same asm doc entry covers VL = 128, 256, and 512-bit versions, the vector width of the instruction.)

**In asm, a YMM register is the low half of a ZMM register, and writing a YMM zeroes the upper bits out to the CPU's max supported vector width** (just like writing EAX zero-extends into RAX).

The intrinsic you picked is for the masked version, so it *requires* AVX-512 (EVEX encoding), thus VLMAX is at least 512<sup>1</sup>.  If the mask is a constant all-ones, it could get optimized to the AVX2 VEX encoding, but both still zero high bits of the full register out to VLMAX.

### This is meaningless for intrinsics

The intrinsics API just has `__m256` and `__m512` types; an `__m256` is *not* implicitly the low half of an `__m512`.  You can use `_mm512_castps256_ps512` to get a `__m512` with your `__m256` as the low half, but [the API documentation says](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#techs=MMX,SSE,SSE2,SSE3,SSSE3,SSE4_1,SSE4_2,AVX,AVX2,AVX_512,Other&text=_mm512_castps2&ig_expand=4405,5863,4306,5433,5406,4103,710) "*the upper 256 bits of the result are undefined*".  So if you use it on a function arg, it doesn't force it to `vmovaps ymm7, ymm0` or something to zero-extend into a ZMM register in case the caller left high garbage.

If you use `_mm512_castps256_ps512` on a `__m256` that came from an intrinsic in this function, it pretty much always will happen to compile with a zeroed high half whether it stayed in a reg or got stored/reloaded, but that's *not* guaranteed by the API.  (If the compiler chose to combine a previous calculation with something else, using a 512-bit operation, you could plausibly end up with a non-zero high half.)   If you want high zeros, there's no equivalent to `_mm256_set_m128 (__m128 hi, __m128 lo)`, so you need some other explicit way.

---

**Footnote 1**: Or with some hypothetical future extension, `VLMAX` aka `MAXVL` could be even wider. It's determined by the current value of XCR0.   This documentation is telling you these instructions will still zero out to whatever that is.

(I haven't looked into whether changing VLMAX is possible on a machine supporting AVX-512, or if it's read-only.  IDK how the CPU would handle it if you can change it, like maybe not running 512-bit instructions at all.  Mainstream OSes certainly don't do this even if it's possible with privileged operations.)

SSE didn't have any defined mechanism for extension to wider vectors, and some existing code (notably Windows kernel drivers) manually saved/restored a few XMM registers for their own use.  To support that, AVX decided that legacy SSE would leave the high part of YMM/ZMM registers unmodified.  But to run existing machine code using non-VEX legacy SSE encodings efficiently, it needed expensive state transitions (Haswell and Ice Lake) and/or false dependencies (Skylake): [Why is this SSE code 6 times slower without VZEROUPPER on Skylake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41303780/why-is-this-sse-code-6-times-slower-without-vzeroupper-on-skylake)

Intel wasn't going to make this mistake again, so they defined AVX as zeroing out to whatever vector width the CPU supports, and document it clearly in every AVX and AVX-512 instruction encoding.  Thus VEX and EVEX can be mixed freely, even being useful to save machine-code size:

- [What is the most efficient way to clear a single or a few ZMM registers on Knights Landing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44578967/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clear-a-single-or-a-few-zmm-registers-on-knigh)
- [What is the penalty of mixing EVEX and VEX encoded scheme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46080327/what-is-the-penalty-of-mixing-evex-and-vex-encoded-scheme) (none), with an answer discussing more details of why SSE/AVX penalties are a thing.
- https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-isa-extensions/topic/301853 Agner Fog's 2008 post on Intel's forums about AVX, when it was first announced, pointing out the problem created by the lack of foresight with SSE.
- [Does vzeroall zero registers ymm16 to ymm31?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59902442/does-vzeroall-zero-registers-ymm16-to-ymm31) - interestingly no; since they're not accessible via legacy SSE instructions, they can't be part of a dirty-uppers problem.

Answer (score 2):

Bits in the registers are numbered with high indices on the “left” and low indices on the “right”. This matches how we write and talk about binary numerals: 10010<sub>2</sub> is the binary numeral for 18, with bit number 4, representing 2<sup>4</sup> = 16, on the left and bit number 0, representing 2<sup>0</sup> = 1, on the right.

R[*m*:*n*] denotes the set of bits of register R from *m* down to *n*, with *m* being the “left” end of the set and *n* being the “right” end. If *m* is less than *n*, then it is the empty set. Therefore, for registers with 512 bits, `dst[511:256] := 0` says to set bits 511 to 256 to zero, and, for registers with 256 bits, `dst[255:256] := 0` says to do nothing.

Comment: Isn't m:n setting the bits from n to m, assuming we are counting upwards?

Comment: @Brotcrunsher: Counting upwards from 256 to 255 is an empty count.

Comment: But why would documentation specify to do nothing? Also, for `_mm512_mask_permutexvar_ps` it says `dst[MAX:512] := 0`

Comment: @rustyx It's not specifying that it will do nothing, it's specifying what will happen when the register size is larger than 256 or 512. This allows for clearly defined behaviour if Intel or AMD ever add something like AVX-1024.

Comment: @rustyx: This specific intrinsic is the masked version, so it's only usable on CPUs with AVX-512.  Thus `MAX` is always at least 512.  Of course, the same documentation applies for 512-bit operations, and for AVX operations where 256 is the max width.  Then it's just saying there is no zero-extension to the full register because this is already the top, except on future CPUs running the same binary.  Also note that this documentation makes no sense for intrinsics, only asm.  See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`dst[MAX:256] := 0` sets all bits above (and including) 256th bit to zero. It is only relevant to registers having more than 256 bits. So MAX can be 256 if the register is 256 bits long or 512 if the processor is using 512 bits registers.

Comment: But `__m256` is already only 256 bit long, so there does not seem to be a 256th bit. I seem to be missing / not understanding something.

Comment: @Brotcrunsher I do not know how to explain it more simple. **If** register has more than 256 bits then bits above 256 will be zeroed.

Comment: Maybe I am confused by the term "register" in this context. When I read register I think about a CPU register, which AFAIK is typically 64 bit nowadays, yet we are able to do 128 bit operations with intrinsics. So, what does "register" really mean in this context?

Comment: @Brotcrunsher AVX-512 registers are 512 bits long. That definition is generic

Comment: @0___________: AVX has 128-bit registers. AVX2 has 256-bit registers. AVX-512 has 512-bit registers.

Comment: @EricPostpischil as I wrote the definition is generic. If particular processor has 512 bits registers the upper 256 will be zeroed. I do not know how to explain it more simpler.

Comment: @0___________: AVX has 128-bit registers. AVX2 has 256-bit registers. AVX-512 has 512-bit registers. I do not know how to explain it more simply.

Comment: @Brotcrunsher In x86 the registers AX, EAX, and RAX are all the same register, just accessing different sizes (16, 32, 64), likewise with AVX and SSE there is XMM(0-15), YMM(0-15), and ZMM(0-31) with sizes 128, 256, and 512, accessing XMM0 will access the low 128 bits of the full 256 bit YMM0 register on an AVX2 capable processor, or the low 128 bits of the full 512 bit ZMM0 register on an AVX-512 capable processor. This is stating that the high order bits will be zeroed, thus removing a data dependency.