# How could I write 8 bytes of data to memory at once in 16-bit mode by nasm?

Tags: assembly, x86-16

NASM compiler remind me the following code is error, "error: instruction not supported in 16-bit mode".

```
[bits 16]
xor ax, ax
mov ds, ax
mov qword [ds:0x0], 0x0
```

But the following code is ok:

```
[bits 16]
xor ax, ax
mov ds, ax
mov dword [ds:0x0], 0x0
mov dword [ds:0x0], 0x0
```

Who can tell me the reasons, I just want to write 8 bytes of data to memory at once in 16-bit mode.

I try to set some data to memory.

Comment: 64 bit instructions are only supported in 64 bit mode.  16 and 32 bit instructions are supported in all modes.  That's just how this works.

Comment: Unrelated: In NASM you shouldn't use an explicit `ds:` segment override, unless the address has a base register of `bp`, `ebp`, or `esp`. In all other cases the `ds` segment is the default, and explicitly writing it will make NASM emit an unneeded prefix byte.

Comment: With a single 64-bit store instruction, your only option is x87 (e.g. `fild` / `fistp`, or `fldz` / `fistp`), or MMX or SSE (`xorps xmm0,xmm0` / `movlps [0], xmm0`).  If the address is aligned, these are guaranteed atomic on P5 Pentium or later.  And being a single instruction, they're atomic wrt. interrupts on anything, in case that matters.  (Unless the x87 `fistp` is emulated by a trap to software on a CPU without hardware x87.)

Comment: Since you're zeroing a register anyway and writing code that requires a 386 or later (for dword operand-size for `mov`), you could save code size with `xor esi, esi` / `mov ds, si` / `mov [si], esi` / `mov [si+4], esi` to replace all the displacements and immediates with that register (except for the `+4`; your second example stores 4 bytes to the same place twice).  12 bytes total vs. your 22 even after removing the redundant `ds` prefixes.  I picked ESI instead EAX because `[si]` is a valid 16-bit addressing-mode so we wouldn't need address-size prefixes on those instructions for `[eax]`.

Comment: If you're in real mode, it's somewhat hard to believe that you really need to zero the first two interrupt vectors with a single write.

Answer (score 3):

> How could I write 8 bytes of data to memory at once in 16-bit mode by nasm?

To write exactly 8 bytes of data at once in real mode, your choices are:

a) The `cmpxch8b` instruction, which requires a Pentium CPU or later

b) A floating point store (`fst` or `fstp`), which requires an FPU and that it's valid for double precision floating point's encoding.

c) The `movq` instruction, which requires a CPU that supports MMX.

You might also be able to write more than 8 bytes (e.g. read the last 8 bytes, then write 16 bytes with `pusha` so that the last 8 bytes are the same as they were previously). In that case, there's no atomicity guarantee with `pusha` (or `pushad`) so it may or may not meet your definition of "at once". There are multiple SSE and AVX stores that could work if your CPU is new enough to support them (if you do the required setup where necessary).

Of course if you don't need atomicity then it's easier to just do a pair of 32-bit stores (which requires an 80386 or later CPUs), like:

```
    mov dword [ds:0x0], 0x0
    mov dword [ds:0x0 + 4], 0x0
```

..or four 16-bit stores (which will work on all 80x86 CPUs in real mode).

The other alternative is to use no instructions at all, like:

```
        section .data
    dq 0                 ;Create 8 bytes of explicitly zeroed memory
        section .text
```

> Who can tell me the reasons, I just want to write 8 bytes of data to memory at once in 16-bit mode.

There are always limits, and 8 bytes is four times as much as "16-bit" (or 2 bytes) was originally designed for. Over the years the limits have been increased with the introduction of new features (e.g. from 16-bit to 32-bit). The last increase (up to 64-bit) couldn't be made compatible with real mode due to not having enough previously unused opcodes that could become size override prefixes (AMD literally recycled previously used opcodes to make 64-bit code viable).

Comment: https://pushbx.org/ecm/doc/insref.htm#insCMPXCHG8B `cmpxchg8b` seems to be written with a G. Also, changing the `mov dword [...], 0` to `and dword [...], 0` may be an optimisation if the flags needn't be preserved.

Comment: `fild` / `fistp` can copy any 64-bit integer bit-pattern unmodified (unless perhaps the FPU precision bits were set to round the 64-bit mantissa to 52 bits).  GCC `-m32 -march=pentium` uses `fild` / `fistp` for `std::atomic<uint64_t>`  `.load` and `.store`  https://godbolt.org/z/TW5EqrM9v  . You can also `fldz` I guess if you want to store a constant 0, and that works with just `fst` or `fstp`, no need for conversion to integer.

Comment: @ecm: `and dword [...], 0` saves code-size (1-byte immediate vs. 3), but is slower (load+ALU+store instead of just store).  A cheaper way to save more code size is to zero a register like `xor esi,esi` and use that for the address and data (In 16-bit mode, `mov [si], esi` is a 3-byte instruction, vs. 9 for `mov dword [0], 0`).  The other thing that would save code-size is removing the useless `ds:` prefixes as you commented under the question, since this is NASM syntax.

Comment: AVX (and AVX-512) aren't available in real mode: VEX and EVEX prefixes work as traps in that case, [which some software depended on for querying the VM in Virtual-8086 mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37829075/is-pipelining-oooe-available-on-modern-x86-processors-when-running-in-real-mode/37831392#37831392).  They work in 16-bit protected mode, but the OP's zeroing of `ds` strongly suggests real mode.

Answer (score 2):

With a single 64-bit store instruction, your options include x87, like `fild` / `fistp` to copy an arbitrary 64-bit integer.  Or `fldz` / `fstp` to store a zero.  On old CPUs this is probably not faster than two integer stores, and maybe not even on Pentium or newer CPUs.

Or MMX or SSE (`xorps xmm0,xmm0` / `movlps [0], xmm0`).
MMX `pxor mm0, mm0` / `movq [0], mm0` would require an `emms` before you could use x87 insns, so prefer SSE if available (Pentium 3 or later).  Especially if you want to zero *more* than 8 bytes, like 16 at a time, or consider `rep stosd`: optimized microcode on P6 and later CPUs will use wide stores if available, and it's not terrible on old CPUs.

If the address is aligned, these are [guaranteed atomic on P5 Pentium or later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36624881/why-is-integer-assignment-on-a-naturally-aligned-variable-atomic-on-x86/36685056#36685056). And being a single instruction, they're atomic wrt. interrupts on anything, in case that matters. (Unless the x87 `fistp` is emulated by a trap to software on an old CPU without hardware x87.)
Fun fact: GCC `-m32 -march=pentium` or ppro without SSE uses `fild` / `fistp` for `std::atomic<uint64_t>` `.load` and `.store` ([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGe1wAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxBIAzKQADqgKhE4MHt6%2BekkpjgJBIeEsUTFc8XaYDmlCBEzEBBk%2Bfly2mPZ5DDV1BAVhkdFxtrX1jVktCsM9wX3FA2UAlLaoXsTI7BzmscHI3lgA1CaxbkxELHimsdgmGgCCm9u7mAdHE/iCAHQIh1e31zcA9P89sRMAQVgw9sE9tgACIADRA2BucL2/GIe1iZgAtBFCHsWBhMH8vMECAA2SQAfQIe1oqCY6AgrxAIBOqDOFzcJMEFOp3wOZjJTHmJgA7FZbnspcDQeC9kx3nSGRARbEJXdRTC/n8AG6oPDoPYTEiYJkEdAstkcw5c0m8gj88xC0h7bnkqk0nViEXiv7SvaAvYAcTcbnlDENO0MwFdFQUCloAE89hFlgw1nsvbQ9kRw6gCAhokbasgANa01CiWh%2B6UK40giBZl3MkBsAnEROUkhYYiUkH0JhKVXqsVa24cRa0TgAVl4fg4WlIqE4bms1iNy1WT02PFIBE0E8WpZAgvesWnAE4zBpz1ILxfRRpRfpOJI5wel5xeAoQBo9wfFjgWAkDQFgEjoaJyEoUDwPoGJgDKMw%2BDoAhoh/CAIg/XFmA7Thd2wupEwAeQibRKn3bheFAthBCIhgkw/LAIi8YBjloWgf0o0gsBYaNxAXXh8BBKodUwTjF0wVRKi8VC8N4Uk2g/Wg8AiYhCI8LAPwIYg8BYOTFioAxgAUAA1PBMAAdyIhJGDkmRBBEMR2Ckez5CUNQP10eIDCMFA10sfQVJ/SBFlQBIOk4rEWExPYsSI2JYt41YvliGEbMEPAfESkFgASOoWEOGFF1QUTiB0rBgpVVp2jSFwI1GZpSECaYihKbJklSAQGva3I0l6Vq5mq8jqkmbrxjaYaBC6ep%2Bv6Uohm6MaFpmlq5okRYFE3NZ1pfDhZ1Iedis4PZVAADjJLEKT2YBkGQPYyneMw9ggXBCBIAVYi4eZeAorR5kWQsGQGKrj0xd4nwvU7p0%2ByQzEkC8yXOsldrfA6P2XDhv1/f8BMAmAoHxiAQPZWDIIoCAYIg%2BDEOQ2hUOIdDMIE0gCNwrjWeI0jyLs6jGAIOiGOZpiWLYji7J4vj1kXIThtE8TeEk6TZK4hSp2Z5TVPUwktJ0vTKIMozTPMqz0rs/gHKrZzpHNtyVHUZndBaHzjH8mwNcq0LwrSSLoqeuLYl4EronKsT4A2iaqmcCBXCW5rCjWlock69JPCaHrk9m2Z5oqSPOlG1OxiG3PpqmeOs70CZFoLxrK5Wsu2q%2BpYVm2xu1f2w7A%2BOs6Lqum67oep6XvwIh0R3b6cb%2Bo8QFiSR3lFR8ny4RHpw0MoySd19eD0le0eZjGsb/X6J1IIDEBQEmqagimL7gkAEMxWn6cZrDgkIuyOZIsiHB59kaP5%2BjEyMUwMxViYgxZcQlkYfi0s8DCUcHLD8itkAyXWLuVWSkVJqQ7BpKWP1db6T4IbMyllrK2S4jbRy4gXI20UHbTyJ59DRj8pYawgUIgeyXF7AQkUiJmEDqVEOHCc4dDqu4au/gIyZwbokDqHQlpJw6FIwawiRpV0yDXCOHQS5KOzvndRFdJg6J2ptZuzlJwznfHvLu51LqSGurde6sRHrPVeiPD6X0foAQBpgIGMQqpq1RtvP8HdPyY1sNjI%2B/1SDHkkFwd404yQaAvJIWIM8zAr0SRSXaAdd5HTCZE8xHA%2BG5M7vkrxpBSopGcJIIAA%3D))

---

Since you're zeroing a register anyway and writing code that requires a 386 or later (for `dword` operand-size for `mov`), you could save code size by  replacing all the displacements and immediates with that register (except for the +4; your second example stores 4 bytes to the same place twice)

```
 xor esi, esi          ; 3 bytes (in 16-bit mode, including the 66 operand-size prefix)
 mov ds, si            ; 2 bytes
 mov [si + 0], esi     ; 3 bytes (66-prefix + opcode + modrm)
 mov [si + 4], esi     ; 4 bytes (66-prefix + opcode + modrm + disp8)
```

12 bytes total vs. your 22 even after removing the redundant `ds` prefixes.  (In NASM, `[ds:0]` emits an actual `ds` prefix byte in the machine code, even though that's already implied by an addressing mode where the base isn't `bp`/`ebp` or `esp`.  You only need `ds:0` for silly assemblers like MASM that ignore brackets when there aren't registers involved; in NASM syntax, `[anything]` is a memory operand.)

I picked ESI instead EAX because [si] is a valid 16-bit addressing-mode so we wouldn't need address-size prefixes on those instructions for `[eax]`.

Using `[si]` and `[si+4]` addressing modes works for x87 or MMX/SSE as well, like `movlps [si], xmm0` (3 bytes).  vs. 4 bytes for SSE2 `movq [si], xmm0`.

SSE1 `...ps` instructions have 2-byte opcodes (0F xx), later SSE instructions have larger code-size.  `movlps` is the most efficient way to do a 64-bit store from an XMM register.  (But for loads, use `movsd` or `movq` to zero extend; `movlps` loads merge a new low half into the existing XMM register, which is a false dependency and takes an ALU uop.)