# Does compiler use SSE instructions for a regular C code?

Tags: c, compiler-optimization, simd, sse, auto-vectorization

I see people using `-msse -msse2 -mfpmath=sse` flags by default hoping that this will improve performance. I know that SSE gets engaged when special vector types are used in the C code. But do these flags make any difference for regular C code? Does compiler use SSE to optimize regular C code?

Comment: All x86-64 (aka AMD64) architectures have SSE and SSE2. So, if you compile for x86-64 target, the compiler will use SSE registers and SSE and SSE2 extensions. In general, C compilers are pretty poor at vectorizing code, so mostly the compilers will emit non-vectorized SSE/SSE2 code for "normal C" on x86-64.  (I wrote this as a comment and not as an answer, because I don't know exactly what you are asking.)

Comment: I am asking: is it reasonable to supply these flags to clang or gcc and expect that the code that isn't written in terms of vectorized types will gain performance. Does compiler really use SSE instructions to vectorize something in such case, or not?

Comment: *It depends on the target architecture, and the other flags used*. They definitely help on 32-bit Intel (x86) architecture (the code can then be run on any x86-64 processor (if 32-bit code is supported by the OS/kernel), or any x86 processor with SSE2 support). For x86-64 targets, they are superfluous (those flags are in effect by default, based on the target). If the compiler knows SSE/SSE2 is available (based on architecture, or from option flags), it will try its best to vectorize even "regular C"; they're just not very good at it in general.

Answer (score 20):

Yes, modern compilers auto-vectorize with SSE2 if you compile with full optimization.  Clang vectorizes loops at `-O2`, gcc at `-O3`.

(GCC12 enables vectorization at `-O2` but [only when it's "very cheap"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74898622/is-ftree-loop-vectorize-not-enabled-by-o2-in-gcc-v12/74906652#74906652), with `-O3` still being required to vectorize most loops with run-time variable trip counts.)

Even at `-O1` or `-Os`, compilers will use SIMD load/store instructions to **copy or initialize structs** or other objects wider than an integer register.  That doesn't really count as auto-vectorization; it's more like part of their default builtin memset / memcpy strategy for small fixed-size blocks.  (Without `-fno-builtin`, this will also apply to explicit used of `memcpy` with small constant lengths.)  It does take advantage of and require SIMD instructions to be supported [and enabled by the kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31563078/how-do-i-enable-sse-for-my-freestanding-bootable-code), whether or not you call it "vectorization".  (Kernels use `-mgeneral-regs-only`, or in older GCC `-mno-mmx -mno-sse` to disable this.)

---

**SSE2 is baseline / non-optional for x86-64, so compilers can always use SSE1/SSE2 instructions when targeting x86-64**.  Later instruction sets (SSE4, AVX, AVX2, AVX512, and non-SIMD extensions like BMI2, popcnt, etc.) have to be enabled manually (e.g. `-march=x86-64-v3` or `-msse4.1`) to tell the compiler it's ok to make code that won't run on older CPUs.  Or to get it to generate multiple versions of code and choose at runtime, but that has extra overhead and is only worth it for larger functions.

**`-msse -msse2 -mfpmath=sse` is already the default for x86-64**, but not for 32-bit i386.  Some 32-bit calling conventions return FP values in x87 registers, so it can be inconvenient to use SSE/SSE2 for computation and then have to store/reload the result to get it in x87 `st(0)`.  With `-mfpmath=sse`, smarter compilers might still use x87 for a calculation that produces an FP return value.

On 32-bit x86, `-msse2` might not be on by default, it depends on how your compiler was configured.  If you're using 32-bit because you're targeting CPUs that are so old they *can't* run 64-bit code, you might want to make sure it's disabled, or only `-msse`.

**The best way to make a binary tuned for the CPU you're compiling on is `-O3 -march=native -mfpmath=sse`, and use link-time optimization + profile-guided optimization**.  (gcc `-fprofile-generate` / run on some test data / `gcc -fprofile-use`).

Using `-march=native` makes binaries that might not run on earlier CPUs, if the compiler does choose to use new instructions.  Profile-guided optimization is very helpful for gcc: it never unrolls loops without it.  But with PGO, it knows which loops run often / for a lot of iterations, i.e. which loops are "hot" and worth spending more code-size on.  Link-time optimization allows inlining / constant-propagation across files.  It's *very* helpful if you have C++ with a lot of small functions that you don't actually define in header files.

---

**See [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552116/how-to-remove-noise-from-gcc-clang-assembly-output)** for more about looking at compiler output and making sense of it.

**Here are some specific examples [on the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:%27int+sumint(int+*arr)+%7B%0A++++int+sum+%3D+0%3B%0A++++for+(int+i%3D0+%3B+i%3C2048+%3B+i%2B%2B)%7B%0A++++++++sum+%2B%3D+arr%5Bi%5D%3B%0A++++%7D%0A++++return+sum%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A//+FP+reductions+only+auto-vectorize+with+-ffast-math%0Afloat+sumfloat(float+*arr)+%7B%0A++++float+sum+%3D+0%3B%0A++++for+(int+i%3D0+%3B+i%3C2048+%3B+i%2B%2B)%7B%0A++++++++sum+%2B%3D+arr%5Bi%5D%3B%0A++++%7D%0A++++return+sum%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A//+clang+won!%27t+contract+this+into+an+FMA+without+-ffast-math+:/%0A//+but+gcc+will+(if+you+compile+with+-march%3Dhaswell)%0Avoid+scale_array(float+*arr)+%7B%0A++++for+(int+i%3D0+%3B+i%3C2048+%3B+i%2B%2B)%7B%0A++++++++arr%5Bi%5D+%3D+arr%5Bi%5D+*+2.1f+%2B+1.234f%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%0A//+multiplier+%3D+2.0+results+in+using+addps+to+double%0A//+cutting+throughput+by+a+factor+of+2+on+Intel+pre-Skylake!!%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:35.77299704436006,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g81,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,trim:%271%27),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-xc+-Wall+-O3%27,source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+8.1+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.38351320157121,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang600,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,trim:%271%27),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-xc+-Wall+-O3+-march%3Dskylake%27,source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+clang+6.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%233)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),k:30.48018830193644,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4) for x86-64**.  Godbolt also has gcc for several other architectures, and with clang you can add `-target mips` or whatever, so you can also see auto-vectorization for ARM NEON with the right compiler options to enable it.  You can use `-m32` with the x86-64 compilers to get 32-bit code-gen.

```
int sumint(int *arr) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i=0 ; i<2048 ; i++){
        sum += arr[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

inner loop with `gcc8.1 -O3` (without `-march=haswell` or anything to enable AVX/AVX2):

```
.L2:                                 # do {
    movdqu  xmm2, XMMWORD PTR [rdi]    # load 16 bytes
    add     rdi, 16
    paddd   xmm0, xmm2                 # packed add of 4 x 32-bit integers
    cmp     rax, rdi
    jne     .L2                      # } while(p != endp)

    # then horizontal add and extract a single 32-bit sum
```

Without `-ffast-math`, compilers can't reorder FP operations, so the `float` equivalent don't auto-vectorize (see the Godbolt link: you get scalar `addss`).  (OpenMP can enable it on a per-loop basis, or use `-ffast-math`).

But some FP stuff can safely auto-vectorize without changing order of operations.

```
// clang won't contract this into an FMA without -ffast-math :/
// but gcc will (if you compile with -march=haswell)
void scale_array(float *arr) {
    for (int i=0 ; i<2048 ; i++){
        arr[i] = arr[i] * 2.1f + 1.234f;
    }
}

  # load constants: xmm2 = {2.1,  2.1,  2.1,  2.1}
  #                 xmm1 = (1.23, 1.23, 1.23, 1.23}
.L9:   # gcc8.1 -O3                       # do {
    movups  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rdi]         # load unaligned packed floats
    add     rdi, 16
    mulps   xmm0, xmm2                      # multiply Packed Single-precision
    addps   xmm0, xmm1                      # add Packed Single-precision
    movups  XMMWORD PTR [rdi-16], xmm0      # store back to the array
    cmp     rax, rdi
    jne     .L9                           # }while(p != endp)
```

multiplier = `2.0f` results in using `addps` to double, cutting throughput by a factor of 2 on Haswell / Broadwell!  Because before SKL, FP add only runs on one execution port, but there are two FMA units that can run multiplies.  SKL dropped the adder and runs add with the same 2 per clock throughput and latency as mul and FMA.  (http://agner.org/optimize/, and see other performance links in [the x86 tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info).)

Compiling with `-march=haswell` lets the compiler use a single FMA for the scale + add.  (But clang won't contract the expression into an FMA unless you use `-ffast-math`.  IIRC there's an option to enable FP contraction without other aggressive operations.)

Comment: Compilers also use SSE in other places that wouldn't fall under the traditional mantle of (loop) auto-vectorization. Even at `-O1` and `-Os` both [clang and gcc](https://godbolt.org/g/bX31CJ) use SSE/AVX instructions for structure copies, for example.

Comment: *" Later instruction sets (SSE4, AVX, AVX2, AVX512, and non-SIMD extensions like BMI2, popcnt, etc.) **have to be enabled manually** to tell the compiler it's ok to make code that won't run on older CPUs."* 
--
What do you mean by *"have to be enabled manually"* ?  You mean we have to pass the required compiler flags? Or there are some system level settings where we need enable these features? I suppose it's the former.

Comment: @Nawaz: I mean compiler flags to enable code-gen to use them.  All mainstream kernels that have SSE, AVX, and AVX512 support set the CPU control-register bits appropriately to enable them by default.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you for such an insightful answer.