# Is `-ftree-loop-vectorize` not enabled by `-O2` in GCC v12?

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-optimization, simd, auto-vectorization

Example: https://www.godbolt.org/z/ahfcaj7W8

From https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-12.2.0/gcc/Optimize-Options.html

It says

> `-ftree-loop-vectorize`
>      Perform loop vectorization on trees. This flag is enabled by default at `-O2` and by `-ftree-vectorize`, `-fprofile-use`, and `-fauto-profile`."

However it seems I have to pass a flag explicitly to turn on loop unrolling & SIMD. Did I misunderstand something here? It is enabled at `-O3` though.

Comment: SIMD, Vectorize. is enabled by -o2, loop unrolling makes the code much larger so it is a separate flag in -o2 and included in -o3.  many times -o2 will out-perform -o3.

Comment: @Strom: `-O3` does not imply `-funroll-loops` in GCC, and hasn't for well over a decade I think.  That's only on with `-fprofile-use`, so GCC knows which loops are actually hot and worth spending i-cache footprint on.   (`-O3` can be more aggresie about code size, like maybe more willing to fully peel a loop with like 16 iterations or something, especially depending on `-mtune` options.)  Also, `-o3` sets the output filename to `3`, very different from `-O3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is enabled at -O2 in GCC12, but only with a much lower cost threshold than at `-O3`, e.g. often only vectorizing when the loop trip count is a compile-time constant and known to be a multiple of the vector width (e.g. 8 for 32-bit elements with AVX2 vectors). See https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=commit;h=2b8453c401b699ed93c085d0413ab4b5030bcdb8

https://godbolt.org/z/3xjdrx6as shows some loops at -O2 vs. -O3, with a sum of an array of integers only vectorizing with a constant count, not a runtime variable.   Even `for (int i=0 ; i < (len&-16) ; i++) sum += arr[i]` to make the length a multiple of 16 doesn't make `gcc -O2` auto-vectorize.

Before GCC12, `-ftree-vectorize` wasn't enabled at all by `-O2`.