# Error passing by reference when making os

Tags: c, for-loop, x86-64, osdev, function-definition

I am making an os and have booted into a 64 bit kernel made in c. I have made a print function which is working and am trying to make a function to convert hex values to string so I can print them. My code is causing boot loops, yet when I compile the exact same code to run normally in linux it works perfectly. The relevant code:

```
int logarithm(double value, int base, int* output) {
    int i = 0;

    while (value > 1) {
        value /= base;
        i++;
    }

    *output = i;
}

int power(int value, int power, int* output) {
    if (power == 0) {
        value = 1;
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < (power - 1); i++) {
            value *= value;
        }
    }

    *output = value;
}

void hexToStr(unsigned int hex, char** string) {
    int hexLength = 0;
    logarithm((double)hex, 16, &hexLength);
    char output[hexLength];
    output[hexLength] = 0;

    int powerValue = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < hexLength; i++) {
        power(16, i, &powerValue);
        output[hexLength - i - 1] = (hex & (powerValue * 15)) / powerValue + '0';
    }

    *string = output;
}
```

If I change the hexToStr() function code to this (removing the need for logarithm() and power() functions by hardcoding values for the string), it works in both linux and my kernel:

```
void hexToStr(unsigned int hex, char** string) {
    int hexLength = 10;
    char output[hexLength];
    output[hexLength] = 0;

    int powerValue = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < hexLength; i++) {
        output[hexLength - i - 1] = 'A';
    }

    *string = output;
}
```

Any suggestions as to why this would happen?

Comment: Followup question with the basic UB problems fixed: [Error passing by reference when making an os](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71996638)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to enable SSE unit to work with floats and doubles. As well as change how values are passed back. Working code:

```
void log(float value, float base, uint64_t* output) {
    uint64_t i = 0;

    while (value >= 1) {
        value /= base;
        i++;
    }

    *output = i;
}

void pow(uint64_t value, uint64_t exponent, uint64_t* output) {
    uint64_t result = 1;

    for (uint64_t i = 0; i < exponent; i++) {
        result = result * value;
    }

    *output = result;
}

void hexToStr(uint64_t hex, char* output) {
    uint8_t hexLen = 16;
    log((float)hex, (float)16, &hexLen);
    char result[hexLen + 3];
    result[0] = '0';
    result[1] = 'x';
    result[hexLen + 2] = 0;

    uint64_t powerValue = 1;
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < hexLen; i++) {
        pow(16, i, &powerValue);
        result[hexLen - i + 1] = (hex & (uint64_t)(powerValue * (uint64_t)15)) / powerValue + '0';
    }

    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < hexLen + 3; i++) {
        switch(result[i]) {
            case ':':
                result[i] = 'A';
                break;
            case ';':
                result[i] = 'B';
                break;
            case '<':
                result[i] = 'C';
                break;
            case '=':
                result[i] = 'D';
                break;
            case '>':
                result[i] = 'E';
                break;
            case '?':
                result[i] = 'F';
                break;
        }
        output[i] = result[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: [How do I enable SSE for my freestanding bootable code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31563078) explains how to actually enable SSE.  You forgot to do that in your answer.  However, it still makes no sense to be using floating-point at all here.  You could very easily and more efficiently use `value >>= 4` for `uint64_t value` in that loop. Or even more efficiently, `(63 - __builtin_clzll(value)) / 4` to get the number of non-zero 4-bit chunks.

Comment: Also, rounding of large numbers on conversion from `uint64_t` to `float` (or even `double`) would make your function pad with a leading zero sometimes.  e.g. when `0xffffffffffff` rounds up to `0x1000000000000`.  (I don't think numbers can round down to one with fewer hex digits).
At large magnitudes, float and double can't exactly represent every integer, only ones `2^n` apart.  e.g. above 2^23, only even numbers.  Around 2^63, only multiples of 2^40. Using `double` wouldn't fix this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#Precision_limitations_on_integer_values

Comment: Have a look at https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html to play around with how `float` represents large values.  e.g. 2^44 -1 is 0xfffffffffff, or in decimal 17592186044415.  Converting to float gives you a float that represents the value 1 higher.  (Division by `(float)16` is exact, though: it's basically just subtracting 4 from the exponent of the float.  The problem with your algorithm is the rounding in the initial conversion simply because you used float instead of just using uint64_t, I guess because you weren't sure how to round up?)

Answer (score 3):

The presented code invokes undefined behavior. For example let's consider this function

```
void hexToStr(unsigned int hex, char** string) {
    int hexLength = 10;
    char output[hexLength];
    output[hexLength] = 0;

    int powerValue = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < hexLength; i++) {
        output[hexLength - i - 1] = 'A';
    }

    *string = output;
}
```

In this assignment statement:

```
    output[hexLength] = 0;
```

there is written data outside the array because the valid range of indices is `[0, hexLength)`.

Or the function sets a pointer passed to the function by reference to the local array `output` that will not be alive after exiting the function. So the returned pointer will have an invalid value.

Another example the result value of the function `power` when the parameter `value` is equal to `3` and the parameter `power` is equal to `3` will be equal to `81` instead of `27` due to the assignment statement in this for loop.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < (power - 1); i++) {
        value *= value;
    }
```

Moreover the function returns nothing though its return type is not void.

```
int power(int value, int power, int* output) {
```

Also this expression

```
(hex & (powerValue * 15)) / powerValue + '0'
```

does not make a sense.

Comment: The power function is supposed to work like that for my purposes.

The return type is just wrong as i have forgotten to change it as previously i was returnng a value, it is void in my code.

I would have thought your point about the writing outside of array to be fine given my situation (the string is being passed to a while loop that increments until it finds a 0), and it does work in regular c run on linux, either way changing it to char output[hexLength + 1]; or the previous things mentioned does not fix my issue.

Comment: @Kepler_7894i Undefined behavior is undefined behavior.

Comment: (hex & (powerValue * 15)) / powerValue + '0'

Well this does function as intended so that's not the issue, the code runs fine on its own as intended the issue is why it causes a boot loop when run apart of my kernel.

Comment: @Kepler_7894i What is "boot loop"?

Comment: "Undefined behavior is undefined behavior." fair enough which is why I have changed it but despite this I am still having the same issue.

Comment: "I am making an os and have booted into a 64 bit kernel made in c." the virtual machine the code is running in is constantly rebooting due to the code being run.

Comment: @Kepler_7894i It is due to the undefined behavior.. The function hexToStr returns an invalid pointer.

Comment: In that case why does the code work when run as regular c code on linux but not in my kernel.

Comment: @Kepler_7894i It depends on the environment where the code is run.

Comment: I changed the *string = result; to:

for (int i = 0; i < hexLength + 1; i++) {
        (*string)[i] = result[i];
    }

excpet now I am getting a segmentation fault?

Comment: @Kepler_7894i: Undefined behaviour doesn't mean "required to fail".  It may well **happen to work**, depending on exactly what asm the compiler generates, and what's in surrounding memory to get stepped on by out-of-bounds array writes.  Testing can reveal problems, but a successful test can't prove correctness, especially in languages like C that aren't memory-safe and have undefined behaviour!

Comment: @Kepler_7894i:   For non-void functions without a `return`, it's UB in C for the caller to use the return value.  But in practice, with optimization disabled, GCC evaluates expressions using the return-value register as a temporary, so usually `foo=bar` and then falling off the end of a function returns `bar`.  People [abuse this for code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/106067/30206), see comments under that linked answer.

Comment: I have corrected the code above so that it is a void return type without a return. However I am still having an issue.

Comment: @Kepler_7894i Please do not change your code in the question. This only will confuse readers of the question and answers.  Close the question and ask a new question with your new updated code providing a minimal complete program that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Ok. I have made a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71996638/error-passing-by-reference-when-making-an-os, and have put this question back to its original code.