# Operand type mismatch in x87 inline assembly in a Linux kernel module

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel, inline-assembly, x87

I really want to use floating point arithmetic in a Linux kernel module, just for the heck of it. I don't want to do anything fancy, just use the x87 trig instructions and/or the sqrt instruction, then assign the result to a variable. That's about it. So far, I've tried:

```
float sqroot(float arg){
    float returnValue;
    asm(
     "fld %1\n"
     "fsqrt\n"
     "fst %0"
     :"=r"(returnValue) 
     : "r"(arg)
    );
    return returnValue;
}
```

This fails miserably and yields the following error:

```
Error: operand type mismatch for `fld'
Error: operand type mismatch for `fst'
```

Any and all help will be appreciated.

Comment: Whaaaaaat? This isn't a recommendation question, it just has a bad title. Voting to reopen.

Comment: Title has been edited to more closely match the content of the question, and not appear to be a simple recommendation for a tutorial.

Comment: Agree. It's a legit question.

Comment: Your output `=r` and input `r` constraints currently indicate using a general-purpose integer register as argument to the `fld` and `fst` . I think you may need to change that to two input `m` (memory) constraints.

Comment: Side note: When you do floating point inside the kernel you have to take special care to save/restore the FP environment to prevent a context switch from messing up a userspace app. There are special kernel calls to do this [or you disable interrupts, etc. and save/restore manually]

Comment: @Iwillnotexist Idonotexist Changing the constraints to `=m` and `m` worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

**Using x87 from a kernel module will "work", but silently corrupts user-space x87 / MMX state.**  [Why am I able to perform floating point operations inside a Linux kernel module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15883947/why-am-i-able-to-perform-floating-point-operations-inside-a-linux-kernel-module)

You *need* `kernel_fpu_begin()` / `kernel_fpu_end()` to make this safe.

---

Instead of loading/storing from inline asm, ask for input and produce output on the top of the x87 register stack and let the compiler emit load/store instructions if needed.  The compiler already knows how to do that, you only need to use inline asm for the `sqrt` instruction itself, which you can describe to the compiler this way:

```
static inline
float sqroot(float arg) {
    asm("fsqrt"  : "+t"(arg) );
    return arg;
}
```

(See the compiler-generated asm for this [on the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:1.2899450879999999,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'//static+inline%0Afloat+sqroot_builtin(float+arg)+%7B%0A++++return+__builtin_sqrtf(arg)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A//static+inline%0Afloat+sqroot_simple(float+arg)+%7B%0A++++asm(%22fsqrt%5Cn%22++:+%22%2Bt%22(arg)+)%3B%0A++++return+arg%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A//static+inline%0Afloat+sqroot_old(float+arg)+%7B%0A++++float+returnValue%3B%0A++++asm(%0A++++++++%22fsqrt%5Cn%22%0A++++:%22%3D%26t%22(returnValue)%0A++++:+%220%22(arg)+//+%22t%22(arg)+isn!'t+valid+for+gcc%0A++++)%3B%0A++++return+returnValue%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:33.53149965383753,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g82,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'1',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:1.2899450879999999,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!((name:boost,ver:'167')),options:'-m64+-mfpmath%3Dsse+-O3+-Wall++-fno-math-errno',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+8.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%233)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:33.53149965383753,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g82,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'1',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:1.2899450879999999,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!((name:boost,ver:'167')),options:'-O3+-Wall+-m32+-fno-math-errno',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+8.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:34.12203690501957,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang_trunk,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'1',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:1.2899450879999999,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!((name:boost,ver:'167')),options:'-O3+-m32+-march%3Dhaswell++-fno-math-errno',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+(trunk)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),k:32.34646344114291,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',m:100,n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4))

The register constraints have to tell the block to use the floating point registers.

---

### Or avoid inline asm entirely, using a GNU C builtin that can inline

You need to **use `-fno-math-errno`** for the builtin to actually inline as `fsqrt` or `sqrtss`, without a fallback to `call sqrtf` for inputs that will result in NaN.

```
static inline
float sqroot_builtin(float arg) {
    return __builtin_sqrtf(arg);
}
```

For x86-64, we get `sqrtss  %xmm0, %xmm0`  / `ret` while for i386 we get `fld` / `fsqrt` / `ret`.  (See the Godbolt link above).  And constant-propagation works through `__builtin_sqrt`, and other optimizations.

---

EDIT: Incorporating @iwillnotexist-idontexist's point (re double loading).

Also, if it were me, I'd add `static inline` to the declaration and put it in a header file. This will allow the compiler to more intelligently manage registers and avoid stack frame overheads.

(I'd also be tempted to change `float` to `double` throughout. Otherwise, you're discarding the additional precision that is used in the actual floating point instructions. Although if you will end up frequently storing the values as `float`, there will be an additional `cvtpd2ps` instruction. OTOH, if you're passing arguments to `printf`, for example, this actually *avoids* a `cvtps2pd`.)

But Linux kernel `kprintf` doesn't have conversions for `double` anyway.

If compiled with `-mfpmath=387` (the default for 32-bit code), values will stay in 80-bit x87 registers after inlining.  But yes, with 64-bit code using the 64-bit default of `-mfpmath=sse` this would result in rounding off to `float` when loading back into XMM registers.

`kernel_fpu_begin()` saves the full FPU state, and avoiding SSE registers and only using x87 won't make it or the eventual FPU restore when returning to user-space any cheaper.

Comment: This gets flagged: `error: output operand 0 must use ‘&’ constraint`. Do you need `=&t`? gcc version 5.3.1

Comment: I'm not seeing that on my box (gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04)). It even produces correct results. However, it also works with the `'&'` so will add that to my answer.

Comment: I've disassembled the "m" version [suggested by Iwillnotexist] and yours. Yours has more wrapper code. I didn't analyze which is correct/incorrect [if either]

Comment: @CraigEstey That's because the `t` and `f` constraints impose an (artificial) constraint that the input must be in x87 stack registers already, whereas mine does not. To make it as good as mine but with `t` and `f` I'd delete the explicit `fld` and `fst` instructions.

Comment: This gets flagged: `error: impossible constraint in asm` with or without the `&` symbol. GCC is `gcc (Debian 4.7.2-5) 4.7.2`

Comment: @GilHamilton You need to do _one_ more thing for this to be correct. Change the `f` input constraint to `t`, else the compiler may feel entitled to place the argument elsewhere than `st(0)`.